# How to reduce the time for file copy to S3 using Talend

Tags: talend

I have created a small job to copy a csv file of 3 million records (350MB) in zip format to Amazon S3 via Talend Data Integration, using tS3put component. The job took around 2hrs 20 min for completion. But when i copy the same file via AWS Cli or Informatica it got completed within an hour. 
Do anyone have an idea how to reduce the copy time to S3 using Talend Data Integration Tool?

Comment: Does your zip file contains only one CSV file?

Comment: just a thought but run an http proxy (like fiddler) or packetsniffer (like wireshark) and see how the data is being sent from Talend vs the others.  It could be that Talend is using SOAP (which is being deprecated) while Informatica may be using REST, which with 350MB of data could make a pretty big difference.  The SOAP payload would be much larger than the REST payload when aggregated over the entire transfer.